# Need help on how to add numbers to jlabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

So Basically I am creating this pizza program and on one page I have a section where people can choose a list of toppings. Now each topping is 1.50 and as soon as they click a topping a sidebar on my gui would display the price. Now I have 12 toppings radio buttons but the problem arises when I click 2 radio buttons it just displays the price 1.50.

I just want to know if there's a way to add 1.50 to my jLabel on my sidebar every time I press a topping button and when I deselect a topping it would subtract 1.50 from the jLabel so the price is accurate.

Here is my code I have done til now

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author silve
 */
public class Page3 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Page3
     */
    public Page3() {
        initComponents();


      double Checkout1 = RadioBtn();

        double Lj = Checkout1 * 1.50;

        String LM = String.valueOf(Lj);

        ToppingsPriceL.setText((LM) + "0");  


    }
public double RadioBtn() {
   double Checkout = 0;


    GreenOlivesBtn.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(GreenOlivesBtn.isSelected()) {
        Checkout++; 
    }
        }

    });


   return Checkout;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

After user selects the `radio button`, on `radio button` listener you can check how many `radio buttons` are checked, depending on the radio button checked count you will be able to do (radio button checked count) * 1.50 = Total Amount.

Steps.

1. Intially all the `radio buttons` are unchecked.
2. Once user selects radio button, check status of all the `radio buttons` checked/unchcked.
3. Once you get the count of radio checked buttons, multiply the count by 1.5.

Psudo Code:

```
OnRadioSelectListner() {
  checkedCount = getCheckedRadioButtonCount()  //Gets the count of all checked radio butttons
  totalPrice = checkCount * 1.5;
}

getCheckedRadioButtonCount() {
  radioCheckedCount = 0;

  if(radio1.isChecked()) then radioCheckedCount++;
  if(radio2.isChecked()) then radioCheckedCount++;
  if(radio3.isChecked()) then radioCheckedCount++;
  .....
  .....

  return radioCheckedCount;
}
```

**I am using the check box to for your case. Logic remains the same**

Item.java

```
public class Item {
    String title;
    Double price;
    boolean checked;

    Item(String title, Double price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return title + " - " + price;

    }
}
```

Program.java

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScreenOne screenOne = new ScreenOne();
        screenOne.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

ScreenOne.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

class ScreenOne extends JFrame {

    private Item items[] = {
            new Item("item1", 1.5),
            new Item("item2", 1.5),
            new Item("item3", 1.5),
    };

    private JPanel jPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 4, 4));

    private JLabel totalLabel;

    private JCheckBox[] boxes;

    ScreenOne() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        jPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(100, 100, 100, 100));
        setContentPane(jPanel);
        boxes = new JCheckBox[items.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            createCheckBox(i);
        }

        totalLabel = new JLabel("Total will appear here");
        totalLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));

        jPanel.add(totalLabel);

        setTitle("Multi Checkbox Demo");
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void createCheckBox(int index) {
        boxes[index] = new JCheckBox(items[index].toString());
        boxes[index].setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        boxes[index].addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                items[index].checked = boxes[index].isSelected();
                int totalItemsChecked = getCheckedCount();

                totalLabel.setText("Total: " + totalItemsChecked * 1.5);
            }
        });
        jPanel.add(boxes[index]);
    }

    private int getCheckedCount() {
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if(items[i].checked) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aIOR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQvI9.png)

Hope this answer helps you.

Thanks

Comment: Hey thanks man, could show just show me an example of how this would work, I just started coding in java and I'm a complete newbie

Comment: Please share code here...edit the question with exact code that you are working on.

Comment: Did it but  .isSelected to making GreenOlivesBtn = true, it automatically adds the value, the code doesn't wait for the radio button to be clicked

Comment: If you have mulitple selection in the group, please use JCheckBox

Comment: I am trying that But I get this error local variable referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final, Here I have updated my code

Comment: The variable I am talking about is Checkout++;

Comment: Please use JCheckBox instead of JRadioButton. I hope you checked the output screenshot.